# Map ef.core db entity to other object without request

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Assume I have a db entity

```
Class DbFoo {
   public int Id {get;set;} 
   public sting Name {get;set;}
}
```

and `DataObject` with the name `FooDto` with the same properties. In this code

```
fooContext.Foo
          .Select(f => new FooDto {Id = f.Id, Name=f.Name})
          .Where(f => f.Id>5)
          .ToListAsync();
```

we use a `Where` operation on the `FooDto` instance and the db request is performed in a `Select` operation. I want to do this request in `ToListAsync` operation. How can I do this, maybe with some mapping between `DbFoo` and `FooDbo` or other options? My architecture just doesn't allow me to avoid the `Select` operation.

Comment: What is the purpose of of doing the `Where` after the `ToListAsync` ? If you do that you will end up loading your whole table and filtering in memory which is not performant.

Comment: @CodeNotFound I don't want to do Where after the ToListAsync, I want to keep same operations order but do db request in ToListAsync, not in Select

Comment: So this should work =>  `fooContext.Foo.Where(f => f.Id>5).Select(f => new FooDto {Id = f.Id, Name=f.Name}).ToListAsync();`